# Bulk shopping ad group creator tracking template

Tags: javascript, qt, google-ads-api

I am using Google's Bulk Shopping Ad Group Creator and I want to be able to create ad group tracking template.

I have edited the original script to what I have pasted below, and added a trackingTemplate column in the sheet the script reads its info from but I keep getting the error "Cannot call method "adGroups" of undefined. (line 529)."

Could I please get help on this? Thanks. 
:

```
/**
 * SPREADSHEET_URL: URL for spreadsheet to read
 * SHEET_NAME: Name of sheet in spreadsheet to read
 */
var SPREADSHEET_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xP-eqEzlbYCSOfMawK2qYjL3qcLARKT7ohwLqhzHNXs/edit#gid=0';
var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1';

/**
 * Column header specification
 * These are the actual text the script looks for in the spreadsheet header.
 */
var CAMPAIGN_COLUMN = 'Campaign';
var AD_GROUP_COLUMN = 'Ad Group';
var MAX_CPC_COLUMN = 'Max CPC';
var TRACKING_TEMPLATE_COLUMN = 'trackingTemplate';

var PRODUCT_GROUP_COLUMN = 'Product Group';
var PROMOTION_COLUMN = 'Promotion';
var ADGROUP_STATUS_COLUMN = 'AdGroup Status';

var REQUIRED_COLUMN_NAMES = {};
REQUIRED_COLUMN_NAMES[CAMPAIGN_COLUMN] = true;
REQUIRED_COLUMN_NAMES[AD_GROUP_COLUMN] = true;
REQUIRED_COLUMN_NAMES[MAX_CPC_COLUMN] = true;
REQUIRED_COLUMN_NAMES[PRODUCT_GROUP_COLUMN] = true;
REQUIRED_COLUMN_NAMES[PROMOTION_COLUMN] = true;
REQUIRED_COLUMN_NAMES[ADGROUP_STATUS_COLUMN] = true;
REQUIRED_COLUMN_NAMES[TRACKING_TEMPLATE_COLUMN] = true;
/** End of column header specification */

/**
 * Reads campaign and bid data from spreadsheet and writes it to AdWords.
 */
function main() {
  Logger.log('Using spreadsheet - %s.', SPREADSHEET_URL);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);

  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  parseSheetAndConstructProductGroups(sheet);

  Logger.log('Parsed spreadsheet and completed shopping campaign ' +
      'construction.');
}

//Stores results of each row, along with formatting details
var resultsByRow = ['Result', 'Notes'];
var resultColors = ['Black', 'Black'];

/**
 * Validates header of sheet to make sure that header matches expected format.
 * Throws exception if problems are found. Saves the column number of each
 * expected column to global variable.
 */
function validateHeader(headerRow) {
  var result = {};

  var missingColumns = Object.keys(REQUIRED_COLUMN_NAMES);

  // Grab the column # for each expected input column.
  for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < headerRow.length; columnIndex++) {
    var columnName = headerRow[columnIndex];
    if (columnName in REQUIRED_COLUMN_NAMES) {
      result[columnName] = columnIndex;
      var index = missingColumns.indexOf(columnName);
      if (index >= 0) {
        missingColumns.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  if (missingColumns.length > 0) {
    throw 'Bid sheet data format doesn\'t match expected format. ' +
        'Missing columns: ' + missingColumns.join();
  }
  return result;
}

/**
 * Converts a spreadsheet row into map representation.
 */
function parseRow(row, headers) {
  var parsedRow = {};

  for (var header in headers) {
    var colNum = headers[header];
    var val = row[colNum].toString().trim();
    if (!val) {
      continue;
    }
    // AWEditor will add double quotes (") around string if it contains
    // commas or double quotes, so we need to strip those out.
    if (val.charAt(0) == '"' && val.charAt(val.length - 1) == '"') {
      val = val.substring(1, val.length - 1);
    }
    // AWEditor escapes double quotes (") with another double quote ("").
    val = val.replace(/""/g, '"');
    if (header == PRODUCT_GROUP_COLUMN) {
      var productGroups = [];
      var parsedProductGroups =
          parseAWEditorFormat(val);
      if (parsedProductGroups.error) {
        resultsByRow[0] = 'ERROR1';
        resultsByRow[1] = parsedProductGroups.error;
        resultColors[0] = 'Red';
        return null;
      }

      for (var x = 0; x < parsedProductGroups.length; x++) {
        // Product group type and value indices are level-1
        // (e.g. for L1, x=0).
        productGroups[x] = {
          type: parsedProductGroups[x][0],
          value: parsedProductGroups[x][1]
        };
      }
      parsedRow[header] = productGroups;
    } else {
      parsedRow[header] = val;
    }
  }

  // Ignore rows that don't have any useful information.
  var testRow = [];
  for (var k in parsedRow) {
    // Remove campaign, ad group columns and test if the rest is empty.
    if (k == CAMPAIGN_COLUMN || k == AD_GROUP_COLUMN) {
      continue;
    }
    testRow.push(parsedRow[k]);
  }
  if (testRow.toString().replace(/[,]+/g, '') == '') {
    resultsByRow[0] = 'SKIPPED';
    resultsByRow[1] = 'Superfluous row';
    return null;
  }
  return parsedRow;
}


/**
 * Parses spreadsheet and constructs ad groups and product groups in AdWords.
 */
function parseSheetAndConstructProductGroups(sheet) {
  var headerRow = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  var headers = validateHeader(headerRow);

  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1,
      sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var campaigns = {};

  var outputColumn = sheet.getLastColumn() + 1;
  var resultHeaderRange = sheet.getRange(1, outputColumn, 1, 2);
  resultHeaderRange.setValues([resultsByRow]);
  resultHeaderRange.setFontColors([resultColors]);
  resultHeaderRange.setFontWeights([['Bold', 'Bold']]);

  // Iterate through rows.
  for (var r = 0; r < values.length; r++) {
    resultsByRow = ['', ''];
    resultColors = ['Black', 'Black'];
    var row = values[r];

    var parsedRow = parseRow(row, headers);

    if (parsedRow) {
      var bid = parsedRow[MAX_CPC_COLUMN];
      if (bid) {
        // For European locale, decimal points are commas.
        bid = bid.toString().toLowerCase().replace(/,/g, '.');
        if (bid != 'excluded' && (isNaN(parseFloat(bid)) || !isFinite(bid))) {
          resultsByRow[0] = 'ERROR2';
          resultsByRow[1] = 'Invalid bid';
        }
      }
      var campaignName = parsedRow[CAMPAIGN_COLUMN];
      campaigns[campaignName] =
          fetchCampaignIfNecessary(parsedRow, campaigns, campaignName);
      if (campaigns[campaignName]) {
        var adGroupName = parsedRow[AD_GROUP_COLUMN];
        campaigns[campaignName].createdAdGroups[adGroupName] =
            buildAdGroupIfNecessary(parsedRow, campaigns[campaignName],
                adGroupName, bid);
        if (campaigns[campaignName].createdAdGroups[adGroupName]) {
          if (!campaigns[campaignName].createdAdGroups[adGroupName].skip) {
            buildProductGroups(parsedRow,
                campaigns[campaignName].createdAdGroups[adGroupName], bid);
          } else {
            resultsByRow[0] = 'SKIPPED';
            resultsByRow[1] =
                'Ad group already exists with product groups';
          }
        }
      }

      if (!resultsByRow[0]) {
        resultsByRow[0] = 'SUCCESS';
      }
    }
    switch (resultsByRow[0]) {
      case 'ERROR':
        resultColors[0] = 'Red';
        break;
      case 'SUCCESS':
        resultColors[0] = 'Green';
        break;
      case 'WARNING':
        resultColors[0] = 'Yellow';
    }
    var resultRange = sheet.getRange(r + 2, outputColumn, 1, 2);
    resultRange.setValues([resultsByRow]);
    resultRange.setFontColors([resultColors]);
    resultRange.setFontWeights([['Bold', 'Normal']]);
  }
}


/**
 * Fetches campaign from AdWords if it hasn't already been done.
 */
function fetchCampaignIfNecessary(row, campaigns, campaignName) {
  //Find the campaign
  if (!campaignName) {
    resultsByRow[0] = 'ERROR3';
    resultsByRow[1] = 'Missing campaign name';
    return null;
  }
  var campaign = campaigns[campaignName];
  if (!campaign) {
    campaign = findCampaignByName(campaignName);
    campaign.createdAdGroups = {};
    if (!campaign) {
      resultsByRow[0] = 'ERROR4';
      resultsByRow[1] = 'Could not find campaign';
    }
  }
  return campaign;
}

/**
 * Builds ad group if necessary, otherwise returns existing ad group.
 */
function buildAdGroupIfNecessary(row, campaign, adGroupName, bid) {
  if (!adGroupName) {
    resultsByRow[0] = 'ERROR5';
    resultsByRow[1] = 'Missing ad group name';
    return null;
  }
  // See if we already fetched/created the ad group.
  var adGroup = campaign.createdAdGroups[adGroupName];
  if (!adGroup) {
    // Only use the bid on this line for the ad group default bid if there are
    // no product groups specified for it. Ad group default bid must be
    // specified.
    if (row[PRODUCT_GROUP_COLUMN]) {
      resultsByRow[0] = 'ERROR6';
      resultsByRow[1] = 'Ad Group is missing a default bid.';
      return null;
    }
    // Set default status to enabled.
    var status = 'ENABLED';
    var promotion;
    // If ad group status is specified, make sure it's "active", "enabled", or
    // "paused", and set status. Ad group status must be set on the first row
    // that the ad group appears in.
    if (row[ADGROUP_STATUS_COLUMN]) {
      status = row[ADGROUP_STATUS_COLUMN].toUpperCase();
      if (status == 'ACTIVE') {
        status = 'ENABLED';
      }
    }
    // Ad group promotional text must be set on the first row that the ad group
    // appears in.
    if (row[PROMOTION_COLUMN]) {
      promotion = row[PROMOTION_COLUMN];
    }
     if (row[TRACKING_TEMPLATE_COLUMN]) {
      trackingTemplate = row[TRACKING_TEMPLATE_COLUMN];
    }

    adGroup = createAdGroup(adGroupName, status, bid, promotion, campaign);
    if (adGroup) {
      adGroup.rootProductGroup = adGroup.rootProductGroup();
      adGroup.rootProductGroup.childMap = {};
    }
  }
  return adGroup;
}



/**
 * Builds product groups from row.
 */
function buildProductGroups(row, adGroup, bid) {
  if (!row[PRODUCT_GROUP_COLUMN]) {
    return;
  }
  // Iterate through product groups in row.
  var maxLevel = -1;
  var productGroupsToAdd = row[PRODUCT_GROUP_COLUMN];
  var productGroup = adGroup.rootProductGroup;
  var newProductGroups = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < productGroupsToAdd.length; i++) {
    var type =
        productGroupsToAdd[i].type.toString().toLowerCase()
        .replace(/[ ]+/g, '');
    var val = productGroupsToAdd[i].value.toString().trim();
    if (type) {
      //For each Group level n, row must contain values for 1...n-1
      if (i - maxLevel > 1) {
        resultsByRow[0] = 'ERROR';
        resultsByRow[1] = 'Every level of the product ' +
            'group type must have all higher ' +
            'level values. L' + i + ' is filled but missing L' +
            (maxLevel + 1);
        return;
      }
      maxLevel = i;

      // Each row must have matching # of bidding attribute type and value.
      if (!val) {
        resultsByRow[0] = 'ERROR';
        resultsByRow[1] =
            'Every product group type must have an associated value. L' +
            i + ' has a type but no value';
        return;
      }

      // Build product groups.
      if (!productGroup.childMap[val.toLowerCase()]) {
        if (val == '*') {
          if (Object.keys(productGroup.childMap).length == 0) {
            resultsByRow[0] = 'ERROR';
            resultsByRow[1] =
                '"Everything else" product group must come after all others';
            return;
          } else {
            var child = productGroup.childMap[val];
            if (!child) {
              var children = productGroup.children().get();
              while (children.hasNext()) {
                child = children.next();
                if (child.isOtherCase()) {
                  break;
                }
              }
              child.childMap = {};
            }
            productGroup.childMap[val] = child;
            productGroup = child;
            productGroup.setMaxCpc(adGroup.getMaxCpc());
            //Only assign the bid to the lowest level product group
            //on that row
            if (i + 1 == productGroupsToAdd.length) {
              if (bid != 'excluded') {
                productGroup.setMaxCpc(bid);
              } else {
                productGroup.exclude();
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          var productGroupBuilder = productGroup.newChild();
          // Verify that bidding attribute type is valid, construct
          // productGroupBuilder.
          switch (type) {
            case 'producttype':
              val = val.toLowerCase();
              productGroupBuilder = productGroupBuilder.productTypeBuilder()
                                                       .withValue(val);
              break;
            case 'brand':
              val = val.toLowerCase();
              productGroupBuilder = productGroupBuilder.brandBuilder()
                                                       .withName(val);
              break;
            case 'category':
              productGroupBuilder = productGroupBuilder.categoryBuilder()
                                                       .withName(val);
              break;
            case 'condition':
              val = val.toUpperCase();
              productGroupBuilder = productGroupBuilder.conditionBuilder()
                                                       .withCondition(val);
              break;
            case 'itemid':
              val = val.toLowerCase();
              productGroupBuilder = productGroupBuilder.itemIdBuilder()
                                                       .withValue(val);
              break;
            default:
              if (type.match(/^custom((\\s)?(label|attribute))?/)) {
                val = val.toLowerCase();
                //make sure there's a number at the end that's between 0-4
                if (type.match(/[0-4]$/)) {
                  productGroupBuilder =
                      productGroupBuilder.customLabelBuilder()
                                         .withType('CUSTOM_LABEL_' +
                                            type.substring(type.length - 1))
                                         .withValue(val);
                } else {
                  resultsByRow[0] = 'ERROR';
                  resultsByRow[1] =
                      'Invalid custom attribute type: ' +
                      productGroupsToAdd[i].type;
                  return;
                }
              } else {
                resultsByRow[0] = 'ERROR';
                resultsByRow[1] =
                    'Invalid bidding attribute type: ' +
                    productGroupsToAdd[i].type;
                return;
              }
          }

          var productGroupOp = productGroupBuilder.build();

          if (!productGroupOp.isSuccessful()) {
            resultsByRow[0] = 'ERROR';
            resultsByRow[1] = 'Error creating product group ' +
                'level ' + (i + 1) + ': ' + productGroupOp.getErrors();
            return;
          }

          var result = productGroupOp.getResult();
          // Only assign the bid to the lowest level product group on that row.
          if (i + 1 == productGroupsToAdd.length) {
            if (bid == 'excluded') {
              result.exclude();
            } else if (bid) {
              result.setMaxCpc(bid);
            }
          }

          result.childMap = {};
          productGroup.childMap[val.toLowerCase()] = result;

          // Set current product group to the newly created product group.
          productGroup = result;
        }
      } else {
        // Set current product group to the last read product group.
        productGroup = productGroup.childMap[val.toLowerCase()];
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Parses AdWords Editor product group format
 * (e.g. * / Condition='New' / Custom label 2='furniture' /
 *   Product type='bar carts').
 */
function parseAWEditorFormat(productGroupPath) {
  // Ignore * / case which is the root product group.
  if (productGroupPath == '* /' || !productGroupPath) {
    return [];
  }

  var regexVals = productGroupPath.match(new RegExp(/'(.*?)'/g));

  if (regexVals) {
    for (var i = 0; i < regexVals.length; i++) {
      productGroupPath = productGroupPath.replace(regexVals[i], '$' + i);
    }
  }

  var result = [];
  var productGroup = productGroupPath.split('/');

  // AW Editor format starts with '* /' so we ignore first one.
  for (var x = 1; x < productGroup.length; x++) {
    if (!productGroup[x]) {
      continue;
    }
    // AW Editor format looks like: Brand='nike'.
    var pair = productGroup[x].trim().split('=');
    if (pair.length != 2) {
      return {error: 'Product group string malformed. Should have 1 "=", ' +
            'but has ' + (pair.length - 1)};
    }
    var val = pair[1];
    if (val.charAt(0) != '$' && val.charAt(0) != '*') {
      return {error: 'Product group string malformed. Please ensure you are ' +
            'using AdWords Editor format'};
    }
    // '*' value doesn't have single quotes around it.
    if (val != '*') {
      var values = pair[1].split('$');
      // Skip 0 because it's always blank. String always starts with $.
      for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        val = val.replace('$' + values[i], regexVals[values[i]]);
      }
      val = val.substring(1, val.length - 1).replace(/''/g, '\'');
    }

    result.push([pair[0], val]);
  }
  return result;
}

/**
 * Fetches campaign from AdWords by name.
 */
function findCampaignByName(name) {
  var campaignName = name.replace(/'/g, '\\\'');
  var shoppingCampaignSelector = AdWordsApp
        .shoppingCampaigns()
        .withCondition('Name = \'' + campaignName + '\'');

  var campaign = null;

  var shoppingCampaignIterator = shoppingCampaignSelector.get();
  if (shoppingCampaignIterator.hasNext()) {
    campaign = shoppingCampaignIterator.next();
  }

  return campaign;
}

/**
 * Fetches ad group from AdWords given ad group name and campaign ID.
 */
function findAdGroupByName(agName, campaign) {
  var adGroupName = agName.replace(/'/g, '\\\'');
  var adGroupSelector = campaign
        .adGroups()
        .withCondition('Name = \'' + adGroupName + '\'')

  var adGroup = null;

  var adGroupIterator = adGroupSelector.get();
  if (adGroupIterator.hasNext()) {
    adGroup = adGroupIterator.next();
  }

  return adGroup;
}

/**
 * Creates ad group in AdWords if it doesn't already exist, along with ad group
 * ad.
 */
function createAdGroup(name, trackingTemplate, status, defaultBid, promotion, campaign) {
  // See if ad group exists. If so, fetch it.
  var adGroup = findAdGroupByName(name, campaign);
  if (adGroup != null) {
    if (adGroup.rootProductGroup()) {
      // If root product group exists and not delete, then skip ad group.
      adGroup.skip = true;
    } else {
      adGroup.createRootProductGroup();
    }
    return adGroup;
  }

  // Build ad group.
  var adGroupOp = campaign.newAdGroupBuilder()
        .withName(name)
        .withTrackingTemplate(trackingTemplate)
        .withStatus(status)
        .withMaxCpc(defaultBid)
        .build();



  // Check for errors.
  if (!adGroupOp.isSuccessful()) {
    resultsByRow[0] = 'ERROR';
    resultsByRow[1] = 'Error creating ad group: ' +
        adGroupOp.getErrors();
    return null;
  }

  var adGroupResult = adGroupOp.getResult();

  adGroupResult.createRootProductGroup();

  Logger.log('Successfully created ad group [' + adGroupResult.getName() + ']');

  // Build ad group ad.
  var adGroupAdOp = adGroupResult.newAdBuilder()
                       .withPromotionLine(promotion)
                       .build();


  // Check for errors.
  if (!adGroupAdOp.isSuccessful()) {
    resultsByRow[0] = 'WARNING';
    resultsByRow[1] = 'Error creating ad group ad: ' +
        adGroupAdOp.getErrors();
  }

  return adGroupResult;
}
```